# Objects over 100m doesn't show decimals? (Blender 2.79)

Tags: dimensions

So, I saw this when opening my .blend file. I immediately noticed something wrong with the decimals in the Dimensions box. It now says in Blender 2.79 "458m", unlike in Blender 2.78c, where it said "458.45m". Is this a bug? Also, when I left-click on the Y-dimension, it shows highlighted "458.45m".

EDIT: The decimals seems to disappear after 100m.

EDIT2: Same thing with the length set to Imperial. After 100', the decimals disappears.

This did not happen in 2.78c.

Comment: It seems so, idk if intentional change or bug. Enabling "separate units" may help a bit, meanwhile.

Comment: I think it may be a bug, as there is no way to change decimal count in Blender, as far as I know. But it could, as you said also been done intentionally, as to make it less "cluttered", I don't know...

Comment: You can file a bug report at https://developer.blender.org